# Reading or updating a table fails in Firebird database

Tags: c#, firebird

I have created a table in firebird name **emp** and I am trying to get all the data from that table into a datatable in c# using **FbDataAdapter**.

But in that datatable I am only getting the column names. I am not getting the values. The table has 3 rows.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
FbDataAdapter adapter1 = new FbDataAdapter("select * from emp", con);
adapter1.Fill(dt);
```

Code used for reading the data from that emp table in firebird. But in that table am having these values:

[image]

but in that **dt** it shows only those columnnames :( :( whys its behaving so...!!

Then i have inserted some values into that same database table by following command

```
FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO emp VALUES ('11','X')", con);
int ds =cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and then when i again see in the **dt** it shows only the values that are inserted through above SQL query.

Comment: Is the transaction in `isql` comitted?

Comment: @cincura.net :Sorry , what does it mean..?

Comment: All actions are done in transactions, only when the transaction has been committed are the changes made permanent and visible to other transactions. In your screenshot you have inserted items, but not committed those changes. This means that 1) they are not visible to other transactions 2) they are 'deleted' when you exit isql without a commit.

Comment: See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195365/firebird-dot-net-provider-doesnt-fully-execute-query?rq=1
You should commit changes to db using ```transaction.Commit();```

Answer (score 0):

All actions are done in transactions, only when the transaction has been committed are the changes made permanent and visible to other transactions. In your ISQL screenshot you have inserted items, and selected them **in the same transaction**. However you haven't committed those changes. This means that 1) they are not visible to other transactions, and 2) they are 'deleted' when you exit isql without a commit.

After having inserted the items in isql, you need to execute `commit` so the rows are committed and becoming visible to other transactions (like the one from your C# application).